# How to get the size of records in a Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase, I was trying to get the size of data in a `Users` where `Users` have different `records` and every record have two properties `Name` and `Contact`. I want to get the size of `records` in cont. I am trying to get this in android application using java.

structure of database is looks like this

`Users`

```
   Records
        Name
        Contact
```

I want to get the count of Records.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uidOne
          |    |
          |    --- name: "NameOne"
          |    |
          |    --- contact: "ContactOne"
          |
          --- uidTwo
               |
               --- name: "NameTwo"
               |
               --- contact: "ContactTwo"
```

To get the number of users, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("TAG", "count= " + count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

> **To get counts there is only one line `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();`**

**Please refer to the answer below**

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { //ref will be your desired path where you want to count children
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {   // Check for data snapshot has some value
                            dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()  // check for counts of data snapshot children
                           }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value listener

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

//You can use the single or the value.. depending if you want to keep track
thismyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

Also have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689244/cannot-get-list-size-from-firebase-on-android)